# Inicializar e instanciar array en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código, pero cuando entra una vez en el bucle for veo que me casca con un nullpointerexception y nunca llega a rellenar adjunto[0]
¿Qué falla?

```
BodyPart adjunto[]= new MimeBodyPart[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){                     
    adjunto[i].setFileName("VACIO");
    System.out.println(adjunto[i].getFileName());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has inicializado el array, pero es un array de 5 posiciones donde todas valen `null`.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
BodyPart adjunto[]= new MimeBodyPart[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    adjunto[i] = new MimeBodyPart(); // Creamos el obj        
    adjunto[i].setFileName("VACIO");
    System.out.println(adjunto[i].getFileName());
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace exactamente `new MimeBodyPart[5]` creía que así estaba diciendo que el tamaño era 5 y que cada elemento del vector adjunto fuera un objeto

Comment: Crea el array con 5 elementos, donde todos son inicializados a `null`